# How do I change the timezone/timestamp of this jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using this plugin called timeago found here: timeago.yarp.com

It works great, except that it operates in what appears to be a different timezone. I live in Eastern US (Philadelphia timezone) and when I put the exact time EST into the timeago plugin (say 2011-05-28, 13:47:18), it reprints as four hours later on my html page. When I write 2011-05-28, 17:47:18 (four hours later than my actual time from where I live), THEN it reprints as "less than a minute ago"

Here's the jquery plugin code:

```
        (function($) {
      $.timeago = function(timestamp) {
    if (timestamp instanceof Date) {
      return inWords(timestamp);
    } else if (typeof timestamp === "string") {
      return inWords($.timeago.parse(timestamp));
    } else {
      return inWords($.timeago.datetime(timestamp));
    }
    };
    var $t = $.timeago;

    $.extend($.timeago, {
    settings: {
      refreshMillis: 60000,
      allowFuture: false,
      strings: {
        prefixAgo: "added",
        prefixFromNow: "added",
        suffixAgo: "ago",
        suffixFromNow: "from now",
        seconds: "less than a minute",
        minute: "about a minute",
        minutes: "%d minutes",
        hour: "about an hour",
        hours: "about %d hours",
        day: "a day",
        days: "%d days",
        month: "about a month",
        months: "%d months",
        year: "about a year",
        years: "%d years",
        numbers: []
      }
    },
    inWords: function(distanceMillis) {
      var $l = this.settings.strings;
      var prefix = $l.prefixAgo;
      var suffix = $l.suffixAgo;
      if (this.settings.allowFuture) {
        if (distanceMillis < 0) {
          prefix = $l.prefixFromNow;
          suffix = $l.suffixFromNow;
        }
        distanceMillis = Math.abs(distanceMillis);
      }

      var seconds = distanceMillis / 1000;
      var minutes = seconds / 60;
      var hours = minutes / 60;
      var days = hours / 24;
      var years = days / 365;

      function substitute(stringOrFunction, number) {
        var string = $.isFunction(stringOrFunction) ? stringOrFunction(number, distanceMillis) : stringOrFunction;
        var value = ($l.numbers && $l.numbers[number]) || number;
        return string.replace(/%d/i, value);
      }

      var words = seconds < 45 && substitute($l.seconds, Math.round(seconds)) ||
        seconds < 90 && substitute($l.minute, 1) ||
        minutes < 45 && substitute($l.minutes, Math.round(minutes)) ||
        minutes < 90 && substitute($l.hour, 1) ||
        hours < 24 && substitute($l.hours, Math.round(hours)) ||
        hours < 48 && substitute($l.day, 1) ||
        days < 30 && substitute($l.days, Math.floor(days)) ||
        days < 60 && substitute($l.month, 1) ||
        days < 365 && substitute($l.months, Math.floor(days / 30)) ||
        years < 2 && substitute($l.year, 1) ||
        substitute($l.years, Math.floor(years));

      return $.trim([prefix, words, suffix].join(" "));
    },
    parse: function(iso8601) {
      var s = $.trim(iso8601);
      s = s.replace(/\.\d\d\d+/,""); // remove milliseconds
      s = s.replace(/-/,"/").replace(/-/,"/");
      s = s.replace(/T/," ").replace(/Z/," UTC");
      s = s.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/," $1$2"); // -04:00 -> -0400
      return new Date(s);
    },
    datetime: function(elem) {
      // jQuery's `is()` doesn't play well with HTML5 in IE
      var isTime = $(elem).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() === "time"; // $(elem).is("time");
      var iso8601 = isTime ? $(elem).attr("datetime") : $(elem).attr("title");
      return $t.parse(iso8601);
    }
    });
  $.fn.timeago = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.each(refresh);

    var $s = $t.settings;
    if ($s.refreshMillis > 0) {
      setInterval(function() { self.each(refresh); }, $s.refreshMillis);
    }
    return self;
   };

  function refresh() {
    var data = prepareData(this);
    if (!isNaN(data.datetime)) {
      $(this).text(inWords(data.datetime));
    }
    return this;
  }

  function prepareData(element) {
    element = $(element);
    if (!element.data("timeago")) {
      element.data("timeago", { datetime: $t.datetime(element) });
      var text = $.trim(element.text());
      if (text.length > 0) {
        element.attr("title", text);
      }
    }
     return element.data("timeago");
   }

    function inWords(date) {
    return $t.inWords(distance(date));
    }

    function distance(date) {
      return (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime());
    }

    // fix for IE6 suckage
    document.createElement("abbr");
    document.createElement("time");
    }(jQuery));
```

I realize this problem is something very minor and can be easily fixed if I were to just remember the plugin works on a 4 hour delay, but I'd still like to know the answer if possible to provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated**

*I'm going to give this a shot but I must add the disclaimer that I'm a little fuzzy on this myself so I might be quite wrong!*

The plugin expects the time in the [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which can also include [offset information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). I've now tried using the plugin and this is what I see (at `14:42 EDT`, about 3 minutes from the test time string):

- When a trailing `Z` is used, indicating *Zulu* time or an offset of 0 from UTC, the plugin interprets it as UTC (obviously) and when printing the relative time string, it takes into consideration your actual timezone. This causes the extra 4 hours to be added ([EST is UTC-5 (UTC-4 when following DST, like now)](http://www.wsanford.com/~wsanford/exo/TCT.html)).

  `2011-05-28T14:39:33Z` prints as `about 4 hours ago`
- When a trailing `Z` is *not* used, the plugin interprets the time specified according to your timezone and it seems to work just fine (**as long as the timezone for the timestamp and the timezone you're viewing this timestamp in are the same**). This is in line with what the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) has to say:

  > If no UTC relation information is given with a time representation, the time is assumed to be in local time. While it may be safe to assume local time when communicating in the same time zone, it is ambiguous when used in communicating across different time zones. It is usually preferable to indicate a time zone (zone designator) using the standard’s notation.

  This would not be a recommended way since it's going to mess up the times when viewed from elsewhere since the timestamp will be interpreted as being the timestamp for *that* timezone which is incorrect.

  `2011-05-28T14:39:33` prints as `3 minutes ago`
- When a trailing `Z` is specified along with the timezone offset (in the format of `hh:mm`, only `hh` seems to be ignored), it still seems to work just fine.

  `2011-05-28T14:39:33Z-04:00` prints as `3 minutes ago`

You can see a working example here: **http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/SVgck/**

---

You shouldn't be changing the timezone/offset of the plugin itself since that will cause visitors from other timezones to see incorrect values.

- One fix is to also specify the timezone offset in your date-time strings: `2011-05-28, 13:47:18Z-04:00` - in a sense, a more complete description of the time since it also includes the UTC offset information.
- Depending on how you're generating this page (if it's not just static HTML), the other option is to fix your server-side code so that the date-time string it outputs is in the UTC format - if not built in, you should be able to find a library that does the conversion from a timestamp in your local timezone into UTC. This is how sites I've seen do it - for example, the timestamps here on StackOverflow (or on Twitter and Facebook) are in UTC time - they are then formatted differently based on the user's timezone.

Comment: Hey, I think I gave you the wrong idea on the first first. You format the time like this actually: 2011-05-28T12:39:33Z, so I tried to modify your suggestion with 2011-05-28T12:39:33Z+4 and 2011-05-28T12+4:39:33Z, but neither work. And can you go more into detail with your second idea? I have no idea how'd I achieve that. But I do think it's definitely possible to just hack this plugin and nothing else, to adjust to my timezone. Granted, I don't know anything about javascript nor jquery, I still think so hah.

Comment: @user758287 You're right about the timezone offet format, that was a typo. I've also just tried the plugin and it seems to work just fine when I don't specify any timezone offset (i.e. no `Z` in the string) - I see the correct relative time. Please see the fiddle I've linked to.

Comment: And I wouldn't touch the plugin for adjusting timezones, that should be part of the input data - the plugin works just fine. As for the server side work, what are you using to generate the HTML? PHP? JSP? ASP?

Comment: God I wish I could upvote you lol. I can't believe the problem was with the Z all this time. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I just tried one of your suggestion of 2011-05-28T14:39:33Z+04. It still reads 4 hours ago for me. So is your simple solution of just 2011-05-28T14:39:33 fine for everybody in the world? Cause that works perfectly over here.

Comment: I keep typing that wrong - it should be -04 and not +04 for EDT! I too am in the EDT timezone so I'm not sure about *everybody* but according to the ISO 8601 Wikipedia article I linked to, when the `Z` is omitted the value should be interpreted as local time. With a `Z` it is to be interpreted as UTC time with offset of `Z`ero.

Comment: So actually, that means that when you just put a timestamp without the Z, *everyone* in the world will see *that* as the time, regardless of which timezone they're in! And that's incorrect! From what I've seen (here on SO, Facebook, Twitter etc), the time should be in UTC - that way it can be formatted correctly for each individual's timezone.

Comment: +04 and -04 both read 4 hours ago for me, and I'm sure it would for many others as well then =/. But the simple solution you proposed, 2011-05-28T14:39:33, appears fine for me (it reads a minute ago then). You think that solution would appear fine for everybody?

Comment: Oh I see, I see. Well since the -04 isn't working, but the Z works, I think what I need to do is find the letter/symbol for EST, so it'll just be easier for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, no - if I was in Cairo right now (UTC+2) I would see that time as being `14:39` in Cairo - about 8 hours ago, which is wrong - it should be about 2 hours ago. You will have to either include the offset for the timezone where the timestamp originated or use UTC time.

Comment: No, UTC doesn't have the concept of timezones only numeric offsets - Z simply means 0 offset. Which means that there is no *symbol* for EST/EDT. There is only a `Z`.

Comment: Hmm if that's the case there really doesn't seem to be an easy solution for this. Not a big deal anyways hah. Thanks for everything ^^;;

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I use this plugin. It's not the javascript you have to edit. Look for the php file, in wordpress it's called 'wpTimeAgo.php' it should be something similar to that.

In that file look for this:

`var $_gmtOffset = '';`

Add a number there, I believe that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using timeago in the .NET world, you'll find it's very fussy about the offset it gets. `z` and `zz` won't work, it needs to be `zzz` and should include the delimiting big "Z" and "T".

For example:

`string.Format("{0}Z{1:%zzz}", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"), DateTime.Now);`

This displays as:

> 2013-01-06T12:46:28Z-08:00