# jQuery.Timeago plugin needs explanation

Tags: jquery, datetime, jquery-plugins, timezone, timeago

Has anybody used the jQuery [Timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin and able to give some advice?

I've got myself in a complete muddle working out timezones. I'm in the UK with GMT and Daylight Saving Time (DST), my server is in America using MST and I've been storing all my dates in the database as UTC (using MySQL's UTC_TIMESTAMP()). Yeah, confusing.

I want to use this plugin on all date fields that are returned from the database, so I know all dates that need converting, using Timeago, will be in UTC.

Now, will the Timeago plugin work out that I'm in a DST country and calculate the correct time difference automatically? Can you please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this quote help resolve anything (from http://timeago.yarp.com/)?

> Are you concerned about time zone support? Don't be. Timeago handles
>   this too. As long as your timestamps are in ISO 8601 format and
>   include a full time zone designator (±hhmm), everything should work
>   out of the box regardless of the time zone that your visitors live in.

Comment: I've read this and no, it doesn't really help unfortunately. "... and include a full time zone designator (±hhmm)" - what does that mean. Obviously it means add -00:00 at the end of a ISO 8601 timestamp. But what timezone is the default? If my time is in UTC, what timezone designator do I put? God this is killing my head ;-)

Comment: The UTC timezone offset should be 0000.

Comment: Thanks for that. That, as well as finally finding a related, well explained question and answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163421/how-do-i-change-the-timezone-timestamp-of-this-jquery-plugin), has helped me understand it more. The documentation is pretty poor for that plugin, when it comes to the timezone offset.

Comment: I think working with dates/times across timezones is confusing in general.  Good luck.